# How to merge two XML files?

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, merge

I am trying to merge two XML documents and have a combine result in a new XML document called output.xml. It seems when I am debugging, only the first XML document is combining to the output.xml.

Here is my first XML called Nutrition.xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<nutrition xmlns="http://www.deitel.com/nutrition">
    <title>Nutrition facts</title>
    <size>28 grams</size>
    <calories>140 calories</calories>
    <caloriesFat>60 calories</caloriesFat>
    <fat>8 grams</fat>
    <saturedFat>2 grams of Satured Fat</saturedFat>
    <choloesterol>5 milligrams</choloesterol>
    <sodium>110 milligrams</sodium>
    <carbohydrates>15 grams</carbohydrates>
    <fiber>2 grams</fiber>
    <sugar>15 grams</sugar>
    <protein>1 gram</protein>
    <description>Nutrition facts for a package of Grandma White's cookies</description>
</nutrition>
```

This is my second XML document called nutrition2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<nutrition xmlns="http://www.deitel.com/nutrition2">
    <vitaminA>2</vitaminA>
    <vitaminC>10</vitaminC>
    <vitaminE>5</vitaminE>
    <zinc>8</zinc>
</nutrition>
```

Here is my vb.net code:

```vb
Imports <xmlns:old="http://www.deitel.com/nutrition">
Imports <xmlns:new="http://www.deitel.com/nutrition2">

Public Class NutritionLINQ

    Private Sub convertButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CombineButton.Click

        Try
            ' attempt to load files
            Dim newDocument = XDocument.Load("Nutrition.xml")
            Dim oldDocument = XDocument.Load("Nutrition2.xml")

            ' convert from old to new format
            oldDocument = Transform(oldDocument)

            ' combine documents and write to output file
            SaveFinalDocument(newDocument, oldDocument)

            ' tell user we succeeded
            MessageBox.Show("Documents successfully combined.")
        Catch ' catch everything
            ' inform the user that there was a problem combining
            MessageBox.Show("Files could not be combined.")
            MessageBox.Show("This was probably caused by an I/O error.")
        End Try
    End Sub ' Main

    Private Function Transform(ByVal document As XDocument) As XDocument

        Dim newDocumentRoot =
            <nutrition>
                <%= From nutrition In document.Root.Elements()
                    Select
                    <nutrition information=
                         <%= nutrition.<old:title>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:size>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:calories>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:caloriesFat>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:fat>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:saturedFat>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:choloesterol>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:Sodium>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:carbohydrates>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:fiber>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:sugar>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:protein>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<old:description>.Value %>

                         <%= nutrition.<new:vitaminA>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<new:vitaminC>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<new:vitaminE>.Value %>
                         <%= nutrition.<new:zinc>.Value %>

                    />
                %>
            </nutrition>

        Return New XDocument(newDocumentRoot) 

    End Function 

    Private Sub SaveFinalDocument(ByVal document1 As XDocument,
        ByVal document2 As XDocument)

        ' create root element, and fill with the elements
        ' contained in the roots of both documents
        Dim root =
           <nutrition>
               <%= document1.Root.Elements() %>
               <%= document2.Root.Elements() %>
           </nutrition>

        Dim finalDocument As New XDocument(root) ' create new document
        finalDocument.Save("output.xml") ' save document to file
    End Sub ' SaveFinalDocument

End Class
```

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311530 - Sorry for dropping the link and running, but I've got to go!

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at the link.